# Глубоко вложенный массив в FormData

Tags: javascript, formdata

Подскажите, возможно ли передать в FormData такое содержимое:

```
const formData = new FormData()

const obj = {
  a: [
    { a1: 1 },
    { a2: 2 }
  ],
  b: [
    { b1: 1 },
    { b2: 2 }
  ]
}

formData.append('obj', obj)
```

Comment: Конечно можно, правда не думаю что в этом смысла много...

Comment: Ок, видимо я некорректно задал вопрос. Вопрос в том как это сделать, если это возможно. Бэк ожидает данные с такой вложенностью.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(obj)`

Answer (score 1):

метод [`.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) в качестве значения может принимать либо **строку**, либо **`Blob`**.

Таким образом, отправить что-то другое можно только предварительно сериализовав.

Например с помощью `JSON.stringify`.

```
formData.append('obj', JSON.stringify(obj))
```